# How to solve integration elegantly using contour integration

Tags: contour-integration

Solve this integral analytically and prove the answer:

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\psi}{1-\cos\theta \cdot \cos\psi} = \frac{\pi - \theta}{sin \theta}, \quad \theta \in (0,2\pi)
$$
[To see the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDCdL.png)

I have already proved it numerically using Mathematica. But still can't prove it analytically.

Comment: Please do not post images of equations (which cannot be searched).  Instead, take the time and care to write the equations (in *MathJax*).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a standard integral:

Let $\cos \theta = a$ (and $-1\leq a \leq 1$):

$$\int\limits_{\psi = 0}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1 - a \cos \psi}\ d\psi =\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$$

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for answering!
Do you know how to solve this using contour integration on complex plane? And the analytical answer is ought to be
$$\frac{\pi - \theta}{sin(\theta)}$$

Comment: You have a simple pole at $\cos \psi = 1/a$.